# how to interprete log/journal after failed hibernation

Tags: debian, swap, hibernate

Running `$ systemctl hibernate` shows login screen after a few seconds in Debian bullseye and GNOME desktop.

Can someone help identify the issue?

`$ free -m`

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15755        3449        9848         954        2457       10981
Swap:            975           0         975
```

`$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

```
60
```

`$ sudo journalctl -r -u hibernate.target`

```
-- Journal begins at Sun 2023-03-12 12:48:17 CET, ends at Sun 2023-05-07 17:18:39 CEST. --
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: hibernate.target: Job hibernate.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Hibernate.
```

`$ sudo systemctl list-dependencies -a hibernate.target`

```
hibernate.target
●RED   └─systemd-hibernate.service
●GREEN   ├─system.slice
●GREEN   │ └─-.slice
●WHITE   └─sleep.target
```

`$ sudo journalctl -r -u systemd-hibernate.service`

```
-- Journal begins at Sun 2023-03-12 12:48:17 CET, ends at Sun 2023-05-07 17:22:59 CEST. --
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Consumed 2.899s CPU time.
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: Failed to start Hibernate.
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: No space left on device
May 07 16:58:04 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Suspending system...
May 07 16:57:53 debija systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
```

`sudo systemctl status systemd-hibernate.service`

```
●RED systemd-hibernate.service - Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-05-07 16:58:10 CEST; 26min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-suspend.service(8)
    Process: 12620 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 12620 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 2.899s

May 07 16:57:53 debija systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
May 07 16:58:04 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Suspending system...
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: No space left on device
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: Failed to start Hibernate.
May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Consumed 2.899s CPU time.
```

`$ systemctl status systemd-hibernate`

```
systemd-hibernate.service - Hibernate
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service; static)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-05-07 16:58:10 CEST; 7min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-suspend.service(8)
 Process: 12620 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 12620 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     CPU: 2.899s
```

`$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog`

```
May  7 16:57:52 debija NetworkManager[606]: <info>  [1683471472.6019] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May  7 16:57:52 debija ModemManager[672]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
May  7 16:58:04 debija [12621]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/displaylink.sh failed with exit status 142.
May  7 16:58:04 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Suspending system...
May  7 16:58:04 debija kernel: [ 4203.397433] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
May  7 16:58:04 debija kernel: [ 4215.252282] PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
May  7 16:58:04 debija kernel: [ 4215.252655] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
May  7 16:58:04 debija kernel: [ 4215.253038] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
May  7 16:58:04 debija kernel: [ 4215.253114] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.270202] Filesystems sync: 0.015 seconds
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.270207] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.005 seconds) done.
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.275631] OOM killer disabled.
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276067] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276071] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x00058000-0x00058fff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276074] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009d000-0x000fffff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276082] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x40000000-0x403fffff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276138] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x454e3000-0x454e4fff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276141] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x49226000-0x492b6fff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276151] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x49370000-0x49372fff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276154] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x4ee59000-0x4fffefff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.276384] PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x50000000-0xffffffff]
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.282800] PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps created
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4215.283059] PM: hibernation: Preallocating image memory
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.573474] PM: hibernation: Allocated 1544087 pages for snapshot
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.573477] PM: hibernation: Allocated 6176348 kbytes in 1.29 seconds (4787.86 MB/s)
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.573478] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.575682] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.819061] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.837976] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.843453] ACPI: EC: event blocked
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.843454] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.843455] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.844130] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.845592] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.848788] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.851124] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.853568] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.856128] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.858484] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.860855] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.863275] PM: hibernation: Creating image:
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.086098] PM: hibernation: Need to copy 1541961 pages
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.086100] PM: hibernation: Normal pages needed: 1541961 + 1024, available pages: 2586850
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4218.255333] PM: hibernation: Image created (1541961 pages copied)
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.863588] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.863799] ACPI: EC: EC started
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.864425] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.864457] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.864458] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.865164] CPU1 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.865187] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.865834] CPU2 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.865855] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.866524] CPU3 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.866544] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.867318] CPU4 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.867340] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.868025] CPU5 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.868047] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.868727] CPU6 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.868745] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.869443] CPU7 is up
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.871975] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.957533] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.957983] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.957994] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.958113] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.958167] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4216.997238] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.011701] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.021394] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.312540] usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.472289] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.472929] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.476960] PM: Using 3 thread(s) for compression
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.476965] PM: Compressing and saving image data (1544973 pages)...
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4217.476998] PM: Image saving progress:   0%
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4218.032175] PM: Image saving progress:  10%
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4218.506624] PM: Image saving progress:  20%
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4218.959117] PM: Image saving progress:  30%
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4219.478393] PM: Image saving progress:  40%
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4219.952894] PM: Image saving progress:  50%
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.240624] PM: hibernation: Wrote 6179892 kbytes in 2.76 seconds (2239.09 MB/s)
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.433817] PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps freed
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.433819] OOM killer enabled.
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.433820] Restarting tasks ... 
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.434523] pci_bus 0000:08: Allocating resources
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.434535] pci_bus 0000:3c: Allocating resources
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.437012] done.
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.480901] thermal thermal_zone9: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: No space left on device
May  7 16:58:10 debija kernel: [ 4220.506829] PM: hibernation: hibernation exit
May  7 16:58:10 debija NetworkManager[606]: <info>  [1683471490.7058] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wwan-enabled" pid=13033 uid=0 result="success"
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: Failed to start Hibernate.
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Hibernate.
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: hibernate.target: Job hibernate.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Consumed 2.899s CPU time.
May  7 16:58:10 debija systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4220.879314] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: on
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4220.879397] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1200@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4220.879402] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: on
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4220.895196] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4220.895245] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1200@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523182] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect:883 (card1) Double connect - replacing 00000000b819c3ef with 00000000b819c3ef
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523184] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 9725 (DesktopManagerE) of process 9702 (DisplayLinkMana)
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523186] evdi: [I] (card1) Connector state: connected
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523317] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect:883 (card2) Double connect - replacing 000000006fed4c53 with 000000006fed4c53
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523318] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 9725 (DesktopManagerE) of process 9702 (DisplayLinkMana)
May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523319] evdi: [I] (card2) Connector state: connected
May  7 16:58:13 debija ModemManager[672]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
May  7 16:58:13 debija ModemManager[672]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3c:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.3': not supported by any plugin
May  7 16:58:13 debija ModemManager[672]: <info>    May  7 16:58:11 debija kernel: [ 4221.523182] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect:883 (card1) Double connect - replacing 00000000b819c3ef with 00000000b819c3ef
May  7 16:58:14 debija kernel: [ 4224.765358] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1200@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
May  7 16:58:15 debija kernel: [ 4224.765375] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: on
May  7 16:58:15 debija kernel: [ 4225.193084] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1200@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
```

**EDIT** [Updating BIOS may help](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=683053&sid=811f3ba4a4e3b06e6763f1a90e9166c6#p683053) - but it **didn't**:

`$ sudo fwupdmgr get-updates`

```
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • USB3.1 Hub
 • USB3.1 Hub
 • ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock
 • ThinkPad USB-C Dock Hybrid PD Controller
 • UEFI dbx
 • USB2.0 Hub
 • USB2.0 Hub
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Thunderbolt host controller
 • SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7
________________________________________________

Devices that have been updated successfully:

 • Intel Management Engine (184.86.3909 → 184.93.4323)
 • System Firmware (0.1.43 → 0.1.49)
```

**EDIT** this alternative command [could work](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1424108#p1424108) - but it **didn't**

`sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate`

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/displaylink.sh failed with exit status 142.
Suspending system...
Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to increase swap space [1](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2021/07/18/failed-to-suspend-system-system-resumed-again-no-space-left-on-device-how-to-increase-swap-by-taking-the-space-from-a-different-logical-volume/) [2](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=152498), albeit it is not everyone who advice doing so, and although how much is [not that clear](https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/). [One way to increase swap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745222/change-partition-size-without-reinstall-how-is-it-recommended-hibernation-on).

Comment: If you answer your own question then that should be a "The solution was" statement, not a "The solution could be" statement. The latter one belongs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have enough free space on disk:

`May 07 16:58:10 debija systemd-sleep[12620]: Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: No space left on device`

Comment: Thanks Sanchez, but there should be plenty(!) of space :-/ Could it be the possible "swap" space that needs to be increased?

Comment: Yes. You should have at least swap space equal to your RAM. That's because during hibernate you essentially write contents of RAM to disk. If you often hit swap with some applications you should have even more swap space.